# EntityNotFoundException: There is no such an entity. Entity type: Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Applications.OpenIddictApplication

Tags: abp

Screenshot of the problem

[image: 1]

ABP Framework: preview 6.0.0-rc2

Application / Angular / Entity Framework Core / MySQL

Separate Identity Server

I have this problem while logging in, how can it be fixed? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have multiple requests arrive to server, one of them may delete the item, so the GetAsync function may throws EntityNotFoundException

The safest simplest way is to get first or default, and check if it is null or not